# Quickest way to convert black pixels to white using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an RGB coloured image mask `mask_color`, shape (4,4,3). How can I quickly convert all the black pixels `[0,0,0]` to white `[255,255,255]`, without using any loops, without additional packages, preferably NumPy way?

```
mask_color = np.array([
 [
  [0,0,0],
  [128,0,255],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
 ],
 [
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
 ],
 [
  [0,0,0],
  [50,128,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
 ],
 [
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [245,108,60],
  [0,0,0]
 ]
])

plt.imshow(mask_color)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
white_bg_mask_color = # do something
plt.imshow(white_bg_mask_color)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.where:

```
>>> np.where(mask_color.any(-1,keepdims=True),mask_color,255)
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [128,   0, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [ 50, 128,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [245, 108,  60],
        [255, 255, 255]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it using boolean indexing like below

```py
mask_color[np.all(mask_color==0, axis=2)] = 255
mask_color
```