# Reducing the execution time for the Nested for loops

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

Currently, the below mentioned code take ~6.5 seconds to execute. The shape of image_mask in (1080, 1920).

```
pixel_array = np.zeros(image_mask.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(image_mask.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image_mask.shape[1]):
        if (image_mask[i, j, :] == 0).all():
            pixel_array[i, j, :] = 255
        else:
        # elif (image_mask[i, j, :] == 255).all():
            pixel_array[i, j, :] = 0
```

Is there a faster way to obtain the processed image which would be less than 0.5 seconds or even lesser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quickest way to convert black pixels to white using NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425578/quickest-way-to-convert-black-pixels-to-white-using-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with boolean masking.

```
import numpy as np

image_mask = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(100, 200, 3))
image_mask[0, 0, :] = 0
bool_mask = np.all(image_mask==0, axis=-1)
image_mask[bool_mask] = 255
image_mask[~bool_mask] = 0
```

Comparison -

```
import numpy as np

def f1(img):
    bool_mask = np.all(img==0, axis=-1)
    img[bool_mask] = 255
    img[~bool_mask] = 0
    return img

def f2(img):
    pixel_array = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            if (img[i, j, :] == 0).all():
                pixel_array[i, j, :] = 255
            else:
            # elif (image_mask[i, j, :] == 255).all():
                pixel_array[i, j, :] = 0
    return pixel_array

image_mask = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1080, 1920, 3))
image_mask[0, 0, :] = 0

np.allclose(f1(image_mask.copy()), f2(image_mask))

%timeit f1(image_mask)
%timeit f2(image_mask)
```

Gives -

```
66 ms ± 572 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
5.61 s ± 45.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: doing it in just one assignment like `np.where(img.all(-1,keepdims=True), 255, np.zeros_like(img))` will be even 15 % faster than `f1`